# Batch not executing

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, community, batch

```
MBT_SFFB__Listing_Name__c ='xyz' // string
MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancel_Reason__c ='xyz' // string
MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancelled__c='xyz' // string
MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c // object in which i wanna insert with this above 3 fields.
```

**calling the batch as below...**

```
String query = 'SELECT MBT_SFFB__Listing_Name__c,MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancel_Reason__c,MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancelled__c from MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c';
insertrecords c = new  insertrecords(query);
Database.executeBatch(c);
```

want to insert 500 events at a time. object contains 0 records ... batch is not inserting records is there any mistake in query ??

if object contains 1 record already in the org than it is working perfectly.

```
global class insertrecords implements Database.Batchable<sObject> 
{
 global final String query;
 global insertrecords(String q) 
 {
   query = q;
 }   
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
  return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sObject> scope)
{      
    List<MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c> ml = new List<MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c>();
    for (Integer i=0;i<500;i++) 
    {
        MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c m = new MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c(MBT_SFFB__Listing_Name__c='listing ' + i,MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancel_Reason__c='Some reason '+i,MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancelled__c=true);
        ml.add(m);
    }
    insert ml;

}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{

}
}
```

As i understood the batch apex requires to generate the scope of objects used in the batch job. and start method does IT. 
**In my case** start method will fire query .. and the object contains zero records will provide scope with **null** . As execute method's syntax is execute(jobId, recordList) recordList will be null. Please Clarify... if  i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point in using the query, because you just said there's no data. If you want to use Batchable, just use any ordinary list:

```
public Integer[] start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return new Integer[] { 1 };
}
```

However, that's almost certainly not what you want to do. If you want to monitor your progress, consider using Queueable, otherwise use a simple future method.

```
// Using a future method
@future public static void insertRecords() {
    List<MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c> ml = new List<MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c>();
    for (Integer i=0;i<500;i++) {
        MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c m = new MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c(MBT_SFFB__Listing_Name__c='listing ' + i,MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancel_Reason__c='Some reason '+i,MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancelled__c=true);
        ml.add(m);
    }
    insert ml;
}
```

---

```
// Using a Queueable class

public class insertRecords implements Queueable {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        List<MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c> ml = new List<MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c>();
        for (Integer i=0;i<500;i++) {
            MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c m = new MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c(MBT_SFFB__Listing_Name__c='listing ' + i,MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancel_Reason__c='Some reason '+i,MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancelled__c=true);
            ml.add(m);
        }
        insert ml;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beginner in Batch apex. I wanna insert data in this batch. according to your start method what will it do ? please clarify bit confused.

Comment: @InnodelSalesforce It just calls a single execution of the execute method. If you're not sure how it works, I suggest experimenting to learn how it works. Generally speaking, though, it's overkill compared to a simple future method or Queueable, as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use batch for this. Use schedule apex.

```
public class Event_Scheduler implements Schedulable
{   
    public void execute(SchedulableContext  schedulableContextVar)
    {   
        EventHandlerClass.insertEventRecords('Pass ID of parent object');
    }
}
```

Schedule the above class.

```
public class EventHandlerClass()
{
    public static void insertEventRecords(Id ParentObjectID)
    {
        List<MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c> ml = new List<MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c>();
        for (Integer i=0;i<500;i++) 
        {
            MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c m = new MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c(MBT_SFFB__Listing_Name__c='listing ' + i,MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancel_Reason__c='Some reason '+i,MBT_SFFB__Event_Cancelled__c=true, LookupField = ParentObjectID ); 

  // <<You should add the parent object ID here in the MBT_SFFB__LHEvent__c  object  . I think its either look up or master detail
            ml.add(m);
        }
        insert ml;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global list<MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c> start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c objrecfbpage = new MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c(MBT_SFFB__Facebook_ID__c='a',MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_ID__c='sd',MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page_Name__c='asd',MBT_SFFB__Image__c='sd',MBT_SFFB__Facebook_User_Relates_To_Page__c='a0H2800000B6nR0');
    list<MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c> objmtfbpag = new list<MBT_SFFB__Facebook_Page__c>();
     objmtfbpag.add(objrecfbpage);
   return objmtfbpag;
}
```